# adding a "outdated " maven dependency from different url (repository)

Tags: pom.xml, maven-plugin, parent-pom

let say we would like to add this maven dependency in our POM.xml file from http://maven.jahia.org/maven2/ to a exiting POM file. What are some good(industry) practices of adding com.sun(or tools) dependency super pom  ? new to maven, example or short reasonings are appreciated.

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun/tools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <!-- Note:  (http://maven.jahia.org/maven2/)  -->
```

The existing POM file like this:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <parent>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>example</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>example-common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
<description>example</description>
 <properties>
        <example-version>7.2.0</example-version>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
 <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>example-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${example-version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an old question, but I had the same issue, and this worked. 
Add into your project pom (also possible in maven settings if you need it for several projects), the Jahia repo.

```
<project>
...
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jahia</id>
            <name>jahia</name>
            <url>http://maven.jahia.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
...
</project>
```

If it's in the maven settings, then you put it inside of a profile but need to activate the profile when running maven (-Pprofilename) or via activation by default in settings.xml:

```
<profile>
...
    <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true
...
</profile>
```